# Is Delete Action Method without AntiForgeryToken unsafe in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a grid in one of my views and created an Actions column in it. In that column are buttons for editing and deleting. When the user clicks the delete button I use jQuery to access its click event.

**Here is what my ajax delete looks like:**

```
    $(document).on('click', '.btnDeleteRole', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")) {
            var $this = $(this); //store $(this) to a variable
            var roleId = $this.attr('data-role-Id');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/admin/roles/delete",
                data: { id: roleId },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    // rebind kendo grid
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Here is what my delete action method looks like:

```
// POST: Roles/Delete/5
[Route("roles/delete")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> RoleDelete(string id)
{
    IdentityRole role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    await _roleManager.DeleteAsync(role);
    return RedirectToAction("RoleIndex");
}
```

Since the delete button isn't part of a form I can't have an AntiForgeryToken annotation above my ActionMethod..

Is deleting items like this safe?

Comment: You need to pass the token via JS.

Comment: Do I really need a token per row in my grid? Don't I need to wrap each item in a form then?

Comment: You can use a single token, as long as the JS can get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't safe. If you don't use antiforgerytoken you are exposed to CSRF attacks, as described [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks).

You just need to send the main form hidden token in your grid delete posts. You don't need one token per row, as you have the form's hidden token and the cookie's token which is all you need.

Comment: What if my view only has a grid listing of products. Do I just create an empty form with an anti forgery token? Can you give me an idea of how I can access it through js?

Comment: @BlakeRivell you just need @Html.AntiForgeryToken() not a form at all if sending the token through Ajax. Read the link to more details about Ajax requests if you are posting Json instead of form